# pendulum.tz.timezone("UTC") TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, typeerror

I am facing a issue wherein it is not able to import the airflow modules properly giving the below error. Could someone please help me understand it

```
10:39:36  ERROR: FileIngestion.test_download_file_mercury (unittest.loader._FailedTest.FileIngestion.test_download_file_mercury)
10:39:36  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
10:39:36  ImportError: Failed to import test module: FileIngestion.test_download_file_mercury
10:39:36  Traceback (most recent call last):
10:39:36    File "/opt/managed-artifacts/python/3.11.6/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 419, in _find_test_path
10:39:36      module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
10:39:36               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
10:39:36    File "/opt/managed-artifacts/python/3.11.6/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 362, in _get_module_from_name
10:39:36      __import__(name)
10:39:36    File "/jenkins/workspace/dataaws-1417_web_proxy_migration/PythonUtils/test/FileIngestion/test_download_file_mercury.py", line 6, in <module>
10:39:36      from PythonUtils.src.FileIngestion import download_file_mercury
10:39:36    File "/jenkins/workspace/dataaws-1417_web_proxy_migration/PythonUtils/src/FileIngestion/download_file_mercury.py", line 2, in <module>
10:39:36      from PythonUtils.src.common.hooks.audit_service import AuditServiceHook
10:39:36    File "/jenkins/workspace/dataaws-1417_web_proxy_migration/PythonUtils/src/common/hooks/audit_service.py", line 6, in <module>
10:39:36      from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import LoggingMixin
10:39:36    File "/jenkins/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
10:39:36      from airflow import configuration
10:39:36    File "/jenkins/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1815, in <module>
10:39:36      secrets_backend_list = initialize_secrets_backends()
10:39:36                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
10:39:36    File "/jenkins/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1743, in initialize_secrets_backends
10:39:36      secrets_backend_cls = import_string(class_name)
10:39:36                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
10:39:36    File "/jenkins/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/module_loading.py", line 36, in import_string
10:39:36      module = import_module(module_path)
10:39:36               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
10:39:36    File "/opt/managed-artifacts/python/3.11.6/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
10:39:36      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
10:39:36             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
10:39:36    File "/jenkins/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/secrets/metastore.py", line 28, in <module>
10:39:36      from airflow.utils.session import NEW_SESSION, provide_session
10:39:36    File "/jenkins/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 24, in <module>
10:39:36      from airflow import settings
10:39:36    File "/jenkins/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 51, in <module>
10:39:36      TIMEZONE = pendulum.tz.timezone("UTC")
10:39:36                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
10:39:36  TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I tried updating the airflow version but same error is coming. Currently i am using airflow version 2.5.3

Comment: I could replicate issue in `apache-airflow==2.5.3` but it seems to be solved in `apache-airflow==2.8.0`

Comment: What is your `pendulum` version?

Comment: Related [discussion](https://lists.apache.org/thread/vpwxg8r93nrhnth3q63b8polt7xyvkwm) of the future of Pendulum in Airflow.

Answer (score 10):

In `pendulum-3.0.0` :

`pendulum.tz.timezone` is removed.

You can use:

```
pendulum.timezone("UTC")
```

Or you downngrade your pendulum to `2.0.0`

> In pendulum 3 (beta) there is no access to `pendulum.tz.timezone` anymore
> otherwise we should call `pendulum.timezone` for convert string/integer to
> pendulum timezones

https://www.mail-archive.com/commits@airflow.apache.org/msg299265.html

Comment: The thing is i am using airflow which is using this pendulum internally. So how do i manually specify pendulum version?

Comment: @shivaniwadkar Just specify in `requirements.txt` that no one can go up to 3.0: `"pendulum~=2.0.0"`.

Answer (score 6):

The main goal for everyone who use Apache Airflow is follow [Installation from PyPI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html) for avoid surprises when upstream package is updated and breaks some critical part of the Airflow, for more detail you could check mail [[Reminder] How to reproducibly install Airflow](https://lists.apache.org/thread/b8q1t3pvtky7y7mb2kjt4r2bz5bvz8qy) from the users mailing list.

*Presumably* pendulum 3 support will be added in Airflow 2.8.1, but not sooner. There is no guarantee that 2.8.1 would have this support, so better check [Airflow's Release Notes](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/release_notes.html#release-notes) when new version of Airflow would be released.

### Update: 2024-01-19

Airflow 2.8.1 [just released](https://github.com/apache/airflow/releases/tag/2.8.1), pendulum v3 now is a target version, support of pendulum 2.1.2 keep for a while *presumably* until Airflow 2.9.