# Airflow Timezone settings

Tags: timezone, airflow

Dear Airflow Developers,

I am part of the development team at Kazakhstan company, where we extensively use Apache Airflow to orchestrate our data pipelines and automate various tasks. Our operations are critically dependent on precise scheduling, which is influenced by accurate time zone information.

With the upcoming shift of Kazakhstan to UTC+5 across all regions from March 1st, we are concerned about how this might affect our Airflow instances, particularly in terms of scheduling and time zone management.

Could you provide us with any information on whether the Airflow time zone database will be updated to accommodate this change? Additionally, any guidance or advice on steps we might need to take to ensure our workflows continue to run accurately would be greatly appreciated.

Looking forward to your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that moment and historically Apache Airflow have very tight coupling with the [`pendulum`](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) library. However I want to mentioned that 2.x branch of pendulum library do not updated for a while, so if you do not reconfigure to use by the system tzdata I guess you might have a problem, since this data not reflected into the `pendulum`, this already happen in the past for the countries/regions who change their timezone or declared do not use DST anymore. There is workaround which added [into the Airflow documentation recently](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timezone.html#time-zones):

> Pendulum relies by default on its own timezone database, which is not updated as frequently as the IANA database. You can make Pendulum rely on the system’s database by setting the PYTZDATA_TZDATADIR environment variable to your system’s database, e.g. /usr/share/zoneinfo.

Information above affect all Airflow versions below 2.8.1.

Pendulum 3 was released in December 2023 and seems like do not have this kind of problem, support of pendulum 3 was added into the Airflow 2.8.1 ([see Release Notes](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/release_notes.html#airflow-2-8-1-2024-01-19)). So if you use this version or greater you should be in better position, rather than if you use versions which only support pendulum 2.

And main thing do not forget to update system tzdata, othervise it might return incorrect timezone information. You could validate about datetime and timezone by run python on Airflow instances and execute simple check with datetime on specific dates, also you could do the same things inside of Airflow tasks

```py
root@3af5674023f0:/opt/airflow# python
Python 3.8.18 (default, Feb 13 2024, 10:08:47) 
[GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pendulum
>>> print(pendulum.datetime(2024, 2, 29, tz="Asia/Almaty"))
2024-02-29 00:00:00+06:00
>>> print(pendulum.datetime(2024, 3, 1, tz="Asia/Almaty"))
2024-03-01 00:00:00+05:00
>>> print(pendulum.datetime(2024, 10, 1, tz="Asia/Almaty"))
2024-10-01 00:00:00+05:00
>>> print(pendulum.datetime(2024, 11, 1, tz="Asia/Almaty"))
2024-11-01 00:00:00+05:00
>>> print(pendulum.datetime(2024, 12, 1, tz="Asia/Almaty"))
2024-12-01 00:00:00+05:00
```

Comment: We use Airflow 2.7.3 version should we update to newer version 2.8.1 to use pendulum 3?

Comment: Yep, there is significant changes in pendulum 3, so Airflow < 2.8.1 can't even start with it, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77703615.

Comment: I've just check, workaround with setup environment variable `PYTZDATA_TZDATADIR` work well with pendulum 2. It return the correct timezone. If you use [official Apache Airflow docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/airflow/), make sure that you extend for update packages more important is `tzdata` package, because timezone changes for Kazakhstan published on [`2024-02-10`](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/tzdata/2024a-0+deb11u1)

Comment: Thank you! Adding environment variable PYTZDATA_TZDATADIR to Docker build without updating Airflow worked for us! Also updated tzdata.

ENV PYTZDATA_TZDATADIR=/usr/share/zoneinfo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata