# Not able to kick start Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, pip, airflow, installation-package, pendulum

I am stuck with an error for the past 3 days. So reaching out to the community.

I installed airflow (version = 2.7.2). When I kick-start airflow using terminal, I am getting the following error:

```
TIMEZONE = pendulum.tz.timezone(tz)
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

After lot of read through, I understood, pendulum (=3.0.0) is having issue with timezone issue as read from this link: https://www.mail-archive.com/commits@airflow.apache.org/msg299265.html

I am using pendulum 3.0.0.

So I decided to downgrade my pendulum to 2.1.2 which seems to support airflow timezone call.

But when I tried to downgrade I have now the:

Building wheel for pendulum (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [27 lines of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pendulum
Failed to build pendulum
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pendulum, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

python version: Python 3.12.2.
setuptools version: 69.2.0
wheel version: wheel-0.43.0

macOS: 14.4

This is driving me nuts for the past few day.

Any help / direction would be great. Also happy to give more context if needed.

I tried downgrading pendulum which is compatible to airflow release. I would like to know whether someone else encountered such problem and how did they fix it.

Comment: I guess you could find solution there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77703615/pendulum-tz-timezoneutc-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable

Comment: And to avoid other error, support of Python 3.12 will be added into Airflow 2.9.0 (not released yet)